# Netty 4.0 on multiple ports with multiple protocols?

Tags: netty

I'm looking for a server example that would combine a http handler on port 80 and a protobuf handler on another port in the same jar. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you are looking for. Its just about creating two different ServerBootstrap instances, configure them and call bind(..) thats it.

Comment: Ah ok. I was confused as calling sync on the closeFuture is just a way to keep the program from exiting. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add details? If we don't call sync() on the ServerBootstrap, the code will exit. If we call sync() then we can only execute one ServerBootstrap at a time! How does this work?

Comment: @Marc You need another Thread to start the other ServerBootstrap. They can use a blocked call, but the blocking is limited to the Thread itself.

Answer (score 13):

From my perspective, the creation of different `ServerBootstrap`s is not the right way to approach it, because it leads to the creation of unused entities, handlers, double initialization, possible inconsistency between them, EventLoopGroups sharing or cloning, etc.

A good alternative is just to create multiple channels for all required ports in one Bootstrap server.
Taking "Writing a Discard Server" example from [Netty 4.x "Getting Started"](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html), we can replace

```
    // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
    ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync(); // (7)

    // Wait until the server socket is closed.
    // In this example, this does not happen, but you can do that to gracefully
    // shut down your server.
    f.channel().closeFuture().sync()
```

with

```
    List<Integer> ports = Arrays.asList(8080, 8081);
    Collection<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<>(ports.size());
    for (int port : ports) {
        Channel serverChannel = bootstrap.bind(port).sync().channel();
        channels.add(serverChannel);
    }
    for (Channel ch : channels) {
        ch.closeFuture().sync();
    }
```

Comment: but if you need each port to implement a different protocall, wouldn't you need 2 bootstraps?

Comment: @user2573153 It depends on how you want to organize your code and setup. For example, ```ChannelInitializer``` in my project looks at channels port and selects a set of handlers to add for the channel's chain. So, instead of two separate bootstraps, you can encapsulate logic into your ```ChannelInitializer```. Or create absolutely separate bootstraps if it's better for your needs.

Comment: Is it safe to have multiple `bind`s for a single `EventLoopGroup`? I thought a `bind` effectively blocks, which is why all the examples use a single dedicated `EventLoopGroup` for the "listener".

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield I use this code in production for a long time and don't have any issues with this config. No, the real blocking part here is ```ch.closeFuture().sync()```. ```bootstrap.bind().sync()``` finalizes quickly.

Comment: In your example code's second loop, would the `sync()` be called for all channels, or only the first one? I'm guessing only the first one (since it blocks). So, can we assume it's somewhat optional at runtime? If we have other means to keep the main thread running, should we skip calling it. (OR should we fire a thread for each port just to call `sync()` for sake of completeness!?)

Comment: @OzgurH It's just awaiting for closing the channels. For example, if you want to put any additional cleanup after it or any other reason. Or you need to prevent your main() to finish with finishing the app, because netty uses daemon threads. So, we make sync() on the first channel's close future, if we get back from it - it's closed and we go to sync() on the second one's close future, if we returned from sync() - it's closed too. After checking that all server channels closed we can be sure that the server is down and make whatever we need - finish an app by exiting from main for example.

Comment: Can I ask, what if I wanted to bind multiple channels onto the same port? How can I have separate channels which join different multicast groups listen to the same port? `NioDatagramChannel ch = (NioDatagramChannel)b.bind(5555).channel();`

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I'm not exactly sure what semantic you are trying to achieve, but check this out: https://sam.andrews-home.com/post/netty-doesnt-suck-at-udp-servers