# Multiple port server with Netty 4?

Tags: netty

I want to bind two server socket (eg. port 8000, 8001) within one Netty application.

I tried to merge DiscardServer and EchoServer example to test.

But in the first server initialization code,

```
ChannelFuture f = bootstrap1.bind(port).sync();
f.channel().closeFuture().sync(); // <-- program blocks here
```

The program execution blocks so the second server initialization code can't reach.

How can I start two different port servers with Netty 4.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netty 4.0 on multiple ports with multiple protocols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243932/netty-4-0-on-multiple-ports-with-multiple-protocols)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment the clause

```
f.channel().closeFuture().sync(); // <-- program blocks here
```

Comment: To add a little bit, the line waits until the server socket is closed.

Comment: but when i try to use a command telnet localhost 8081 in a command line in result i have an error  Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys !! it worked. Just for others , I had to add
f.channel().closeFuture().sync(); 
after the second bind();

```
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
    .childHandler(new HttpServerInitializer(sslContext));
    b.bind(4443).sync();

    ServerBootstrap b1 = new ServerBootstrap();
    b1.group(bossGroupNonSSL, workerGroupNonSSL)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .childHandler(new HttpServerNonSSL());
    ChannelFuture f = b1.bind(4080).sync();

f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```